# Flexbox background corrupt when scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a flexbox column layout with 3 rows. The top and bottom rows are headers which should be only as high as needed to fit the content. The middle row should grow or shrink. But, it should not shrink so much to overflow its contents - at that point the whole window should scroll.

```
<div class="flex-column" style="background-color: green; height: 100%">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div style="flex-shrink: 1; flex-grow: 1; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; min-height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wds911zz/)

The issue with this (Chrome 50) is that when the window is vertically shrunk so that the scrollbar appears in the window (not just in the inner part), when one scrolls down to reveal the footer, **the green background of the footer is corrupt** - it extends only as far as it did initially.

Notes:

- The whole window should scroll if it's not possible to otherwise achieve the min-height of the inner div.
- I suppose generally I would not have min-height on the inner div itself but on one of its children.
- The real issue that I have is actually the frame around the outer div (it's a Bootstrap panel), not the background color which serves as a simple test case. See the picture.

[image: picture with panel]

Comment: it is because footer has no background and overflows from container .flex-column set to height:100%; nothing wrong actually :)

Comment: In my real case the problem isn't so much as the background-color but the framing of the outer div (it's a Bootstrap panel). At the bottom it just cuts off going through the middle of the footer instead of around it.

Comment: I could have wrote this too : 
 
**it is because footer  overflows from container .flex-column set to height:100%; nothing wrong actually :)** (about color removed)    the fixed height brings the footer overflowing the box.  test your code adding overflow:hidden to that outer div  https://jsfiddle.net/wds911zz/2/ height set to 50% to be more visual https://jsfiddle.net/wds911zz/3/

Comment: This removes the outer scrollbar when it overflows. I *want* the outer scrollbar to appear but the footer look right when scrolled.

Comment: For the sake of sanity learn how CSS level 1 `float` and `width` work and **dump** Bootstrap; Bootstrap is a client-side framework created by server-side guys. *Every* site I've seen use it goes nuts on `class` attributes. When you see an issue like this it implies you've used a parent element for code purposes though not styling which is where `height` and `overflow` come in to play. Good luck!